# Java Randomized Tile Maker

Tags: java, 2d, tiles

I am attempting to make a randomized tile maker in Java that will mix up 6 different colors on tiles for a 2d puzzle game. The color combinations are astronomical, so I would like Java to do it for me. I have absolutely no clue where to start. I tried looking it up online with no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your problem with generating random colors or drawing 2D squares?

Comment: My problem is making the random colors appear on the 2d hexagon tiles :(

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 4 colors. Red, Blue, Green, and Yellow. You want to make these show up as squares randomly each level you can make a switch statement which says if colorRed > colorBlue, colorYellow, and colorGreen then set this cube to red. Then you'd just set the color variables to a random(); so the colors are chosen randomly.